# Issue installing python3-dev on fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 in Vagrant box

Tags: python-3.x, vagrant, ubuntu-18.04

My `Vagrantfile` is as follows:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Set Vagrant Minimum Version
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-18.04"

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8000
  config.vm.network :private_network, type: "dhcp"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"

  # Determine the available cores in host system.
  cpu_count = 1
  if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /linux/
    cpu_count = `nproc`.to_i
  elsif RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/
    cpu_count = `sysctl -n hw.ncpu`.to_i
  end

  config.vm.provider "vmware_fusion" do |v|
    v.vmx['memsize'] = 4096
    v.vmx['numvcpus'] = (cpu_count / 2).ceil
  end
end
```

I'm using the bento/ubuntu-18.04 box, and I can Successfully do a `vagrant up`, but if I run the following commands:

```sh
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

I get a rather long error message shown in full below:

```
Checking init scripts...
dpkg: error processing package libssl1.1:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libssl1.1:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Setting up libexpat1-dev:amd64 (2.2.5-3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up python3-lib2to3 (3.6.8-1~18.04) ...
Setting up python3-distutils (3.6.8-1~18.04) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libssl-dev:amd64:
 libssl-dev:amd64 depends on libssl1.1 (= 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.2); however:
  Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libssl-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpython3.6-minimal:amd64:
 libpython3.6-minimal:amd64 depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1); however:
  Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpython3.6-minimal:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up dh-python (3.20180325ubuntu2) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
        dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64:
 libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64 depends on libpython3.6-minimal (= 3.6.8-1~18.04.1); however:
  Package libpython3.6-minimal:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3.6:
 python3.6 depends on libpython3.6-stdlib (= 3.6.8-1~18.04.1); however:
  Package libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3.6 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3.6-minimal:
 python3.6-minimal depends on libpython3.6-minimal (= 3.6.8-1~18.04.1); however:
  Package libpython3.6-minimal:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3.6-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                                                            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                        of libpython3.6-dev:amd64:
 libpython3.6-dev:amd64 depends on libpython3.6-stdlib (= 3.6.8-1~18.04.1); however:
  Package libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpython3.6-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3.6-dev:
 python3.6-dev depends on python3.6 (= 3.6.8-1~18.04.1); however:
  Package python3.6 is not configured yet.
 python3.6-dev depends on libpython3.6-dev (= 3.6.8-1~18.04.1); however:
  Package libpython3.6-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3.6-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpython3.6:amd64:
 libpython3.6:amd64 depends on libpython3.6-stdlib (= 3.6.8-1~18.04.1); however:
  Package libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpython3.6:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpython3-dev:amd64:
 libpython3-dev:amd64 depends on libpython3.6-dev (>= 3.6.7-1~); however:
  Package libpython3.6-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpython3-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-dev:
 python3-dev depends on libpython3-dev (= 3.6.7-1~18.04); however:
  Package libpython3-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.
 python3-dev depends on python3.6-dev (>= 3.6.7-1~); however:
  Package python3.6-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libssl1.1:amd64
 libssl-dev:amd64
 libpython3.6-minimal:amd64
 libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64
 python3.6
 python3.6-minimal
 libpython3.6-dev:amd64
 python3.6-dev
 libpython3.6:amd64
 libpython3-dev:amd64
 python3-dev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've confirmed this is happening on other machines as well, also using the same Vagrant box, but with a Virtualbox setup. It does not succesfully install the python-dev environment either. I'm getting similar results when trying to install Postgres as well, with an almost identical error message.

Vagrant version is:
2.2.3

VMWare Fusion Version:
8.1.1

OS:
macOS Mojave 10.14.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced the same issue. It all appears to flow from a problem with the `libssl1.1` package. Upgrading the system seemed to fix things:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This may take a while. At some point I was asked whether to accept the new version of a configuration file shipped with Ubuntu, and I answered yes (`Y`).

```
Configuration file '/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** release-upgrades (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
```

After this, the `apt-get install` worked.

Comment: This did it! Thank you so much!! I let the vagrant box maintainer know that I'm having this issue as well, so hopefully it gets fixed in the future, but for now doing that totally works!